# how to get phpmyabmin to work on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, lamp, phpmyadmin

i have installed a LAMP server on ubuntu 15.04 but cant seem to get phpmyadmin to work. any ideas, i have got everything installed and i also recessive  "configdump configtest fullstatus graceful gracefulstop modules reload virtualhosts" this error message when i try to sudo service apache2 restart.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin doesn't work out-of-the-box once installed: you need to configure Apache first. Add the following line to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i have done this it is still not running... and when i do sudo service apache2 restart i get the error

Comment: configdump configtest fullstatus graceful gracefulstop modules reload virtualhosts

Comment: Usage: apache2 {start|stop|graceful-stop|restart|reload|force-reload|start-htcacheclean|stop-htcacheclean}

Comment: sorry the error was the one i just sent

Comment: @DarkParticle As I understand you just installed both `lamp-server^` and `phpmyadmin`. Try to purge both then reinstall them (first `lamp-server^`, then `phpmyadmin`): `sudo apt-get purge lamp-server^ phpmyadmin && sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ && sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`, then try to reconfigure Apache again as explained above

Comment: ~$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lamp-server

Comment: my server is working i just cant phpmyadmin to run

Comment: ok so i did what you said  got 2 new files

Comment: but i got thisbash: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Permission denied

Comment: @DarkParticle It's `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` (mind the `^`). Anyway if you did everything correctly, you need to use `sudo` to edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`: `sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Enable the `phpmyadmin` configuration via

```
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Disable with

```
sudo a2disconf phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get purge lamp-server^ phpmyadmin && sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ && sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

that fixed it for me.